# Add CSS styled marker to google maps

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Can someone please advise how I could add [this animated marker](http://cssdeck.com/labs/tedyvui4) to the below google maps API.

The below is the standard google maps api code with option to give image source for the marker (icon).

```
function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatlng
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      icon: marker.png,         //Option for setting the marker source
      title: 'Hello World!'
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: Im pretty sure that you need to add an image to the icon parameter, however that pin is drawn completely in CSS. You can add animations to the image but unsure if you can draw it completely. The other option is to use the google map marker object [link] http://www.w3schools.com/googleAPI/google_maps_overlays.asp or heres a good start [link] http://www.sitepoint.com/embellishing-your-google-map-with-css3-and-jquery/

Comment: It's not clear if your problem is making the marker CSS styled or if you want it animated when it's added to the map.  If the latter you can specify the `animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP` property in your marker's options when creating it.  See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-animations-iteration

Comment: The problem I have is displaying the css styled marker (with pulse animation) on google maps.

Comment: I've just found that someone has already implemented the css styled marker in the below link (scroll to the bottom of the page to see that working). http://atmyprime.com/ Trying to figure out how this has been implemented.

Answer (score 14):

Use [RichMarker for Google Maps v3](https://github.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/blob/master/richmarker/examples/richmarker.html) - usage:

```
curMarker = new RichMarker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(position),
    map: map,
    content: '<div id="foo">Bar</div>'
});
```

[JSFiddle example.](http://jsfiddle.net/onxkqcwq/121/)

Comment: How can I add this to my angular 2 project? I got an error on line 37
RichMarker.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();
window['RichMarker'] = RichMarker;
richmarker.js:37 Uncaught Reference
Error: google is not defined
    at richmarker.js:37

Comment: @Wasyster maybe you need add  "richmarker.js" library.
You find here https://github.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/blob/master/richmarker/src/richmarker.js

Comment: Doesn't seem to work anymore?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a modified version of the pulse animator you mentioned that I'm using that works. Basically you create an overlay (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/customoverlays) that you then position by attaching to a marker point.

To have the pin and animation created from CSS I believe you'll need to set the pin image blank and to the correct size with something like this if you'd like it to be clickable through the marker.

```
var image = {
  url: '/images/blank.png',
  size: new google.maps.Size(100, 39),
  origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
  anchor: new google.maps.Point(50, 39),
  };
```

Then make sure the overlay is drawn on the correct pane

```
var pane = this.getPanes().overlayImage; (contains the marker foreground images.)
```

My implementation provided below is slightly different because I decided to use a pin image and only the animation part. I'm going to draw on the overlayShadow so the animation goes behind the image I use for the marker.

JS

```
var animatedOverlay;

// Define the animated overlay, derived from google.maps.OverlayView
function PinAnimation(opt_options) {
    this.setValues(opt_options);
    var div = this.div_ = document.createElement('div');
    div.id = 'holder';

    var span = this.span_ = document.createElement('span');
    span.className = 'pulse';
    div.appendChild(span);
};

PinAnimation.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView;

PinAnimation.prototype.onAdd = function() {

     //Overlay shadow puts the animation behind the pin
     var pane = this.getPanes().overlayShadow;
     pane.appendChild(this.div_);

     // Ensures the PinAnimation is redrawn if the text or position is changed.
     var me = this;
     this.listeners_ = [
          google.maps.event.addListener(this, 'position_changed',
               function() { me.draw(); }),
     ];
};

// Implement onRemove
PinAnimation.prototype.onRemove = function() {
     this.div_.parentNode.removeChild(this.div_);

     // PinAnimation is removed from the map, stop updating its position/any other listeners added.
     for (var i = 0, I = this.listeners_.length; i < I; ++i) {
          google.maps.event.removeListener(this.listeners_[i]);
     }
};

// Set the visibility to 'hidden' or 'visible'.
PinAnimation.prototype.hide = function() {
    if (this.div_) {
        this.div_.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
};
PinAnimation.prototype.show = function() {
    if (this.div_) {
        this.div_.style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
};

// Implement draw
PinAnimation.prototype.draw = function() {
    var topPadding = 0;
    var sizeHeight = 50
    var sizeWidth = sizeHeight;
    var centerX = sizeWidth/2;
    var centerY = sizeHeight/2;

     var projection = this.getProjection();
     var position = projection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.get('position'));
     var div = this.div_;
//Adjust overlay position to be centered over the point
     div.style.left = position.x-centerX + 'px';
     div.style.top = position.y-topPadding-centerY + 'px';
     div.style.display = 'block';
};

//Set marker and draw overlay
function setMarker(location) {

    var maps_location = new google.maps.LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: map_location,
        map: map,
        icon: marker.png,
        title: 'Hello World!'
        });

    animatedOverlay = new PinAnimation({
        map: map
    });
    animatedOverlay.bindTo('position', marker, 'position');
    animatedOverlay.show();
}
```

CSS

```
#holder {
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
position: absolute;
transform: rotateX(55deg);
background: transparent;
}
.pulse {
    border: 10px solid #5bc0de;
    background: transparent;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    -webkit-animation: pulse 1s ease-out;
    -moz-animation: pulse 1s ease-out;
    animation: pulse 1s ease-out;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0;
}
@-moz-keyframes pulse {
 0% {
    -moz-transform: scale(0);
    opacity: 0.0;
 }
 25% {
    -moz-transform: scale(0);
    opacity: 0.1;
 }
 50% {
    -moz-transform: scale(0.1);
    opacity: 0.3;
 }
 75% {
    -moz-transform: scale(0.5);
    opacity: 0.5;
 }
 100% {
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 0.0;
 }
}
@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
 0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    opacity: 0.0;
 }
 25% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    opacity: 0.1;
 }
 50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.1);
    opacity: 0.3;
 }
 75% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
    opacity: 0.5;
 }
 100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 0.0;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used RichMarker for this in my Angular2 Ionic3 project.

```
let marker = new RichMarker({
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(markerData.lat, markerData.lng),
  map: this.map,
  content: '<div class="richmarker-wrapper"><center><img class="marker-image" src="' + image +'"></img><p class="marker-nickname">' + markerData.story.user.nickName + '</p></center></div>',
  shadow: 0
});
```

And the trick was how to import the js file. In the src directory I added the js file to the index.html like this:

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=places&key=MyApiKEY"></script>
<script async defer src="assets/js/richmarker.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -4):

```
curMarker = new RichMarker({
    position: pointToMoveTo,
    map: map,
    content: '<div class="pin2 bounce2"></div><div class="pulse2"></div>',
});
```