# Custom css map marker

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, sass

There is a tutorial im following on http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/jcHqt/ But the rendering of the marker is not so great especially with my own custom marker  its a bit pixilated. i want to use a div instead with css to achieve the same thing can anyone help.

```
body,html,#map_canvas{height:100%;margin:0;}
#map_canvas .centerMarker{
position:absolute;
/*url of the marker*/
background:url(http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/Map-Markers-Icons-Demo-    PNG/128/Map-Marker-Marker-Outside-Azure.png) no-repeat;
/*center the marker*/
top:50%;left:50%;
z-index:1;
/*fix offset when needed*/
margin-left:-10px;
margin-top:-34px;
/*size of the image*/
height:34px;
width:20px;
cursor:pointer;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add CSS styled marker to google maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21238688/add-css-styled-marker-to-google-maps)

Answer (score -1):

Your answer would be in Google Maps documentation

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-symbol-custom  -  This is SVG option

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers#simple_icons - This is Image png/jpeg

[Add CSS styled marker to google maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21238688/add-css-styled-marker-to-google-maps) - Here is a CSS option (Last answer)