# Add css style to gmap markers

Tags: css, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-markers

How can I add `css style` to ui-gmap markers?(angular.js)
for example this code:

```
<ui-gmap-markers doCluster="true" click="'onClicked'" models="vm.map.markers" coords="'coords'" icon="'icon'" idkey="'id'" events="vm.mapEvents" options="'options'" clusterOptions="vm.cluseroptions">
    <ui-gmap-windows show="'showWindow'" closeClick="'closeClick'" ng-cloak>
       <div data-ui-sref="display">
            <span data-ng-non-bindable>Test</span>
       </div>
     </ui-gmap-windows>
</ui-gmap-markers>
```

Comment: i know you can change the marker image try that :P

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21238688/add-css-styled-marker-to-google-maps

Comment: not change marker. i want to add some costume animation to marker.not pre-defined google marker animations @vignesh

Comment: see my answer below. It includes labelClass property

Answer (score 0):

See [this](http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/api/markers)

**EDIT**

Apparently, I checked my previous project and this I how I used it:

```
<ui-gmap-markers control="vm.markerControl" models="vm.markers" coords="'position'"
    options="'options'" typeEvents="vm.markerEvents" type="'spider'" typeOptions="{keepSpiderfied:true}" modelsbyref="false"> </ui-gmap-markers>
```

vm.markers is a array or marker, and marker has an option property. option then has icon property:

```
marker = {
  option: {
    icon : "icon.png",
    labelClass : "some-class"
  }
}
```

**EDIT** added labelClass

Comment: not need to change marker.I want to add styles like css animation. @doge1ord

Comment: can you help me for adding this css animation?[Animated.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) @doge1ord

Comment: I can not add multiple animation css class @doge1ord

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do but you can change the labelClass during runtime

Comment: I want to add two class to marker for adding animation to marker.For example for making alarm on a marker.@doge1ord

Comment: Did you try assigning label class as `${class1} ${class2}` (space in-between). If that doesn't work, combine the properties of both class1 and class2 into another class. LESS or SASS would greatly help you there

Comment: I want like this [demo](http://dylanvann.com/custom-animated-google-maps-markers/) @doge1ord