# How to add CSS in Google Map Marker icon?

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps-markers

Can you please tell me how to customize Marker by adding class or inline CSS to them?
As image is finally converted into canvas that's why I am unable to add CSS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add CSS styled marker to google maps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21238688/add-css-styled-marker-to-google-maps)

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure if you can change the css... the Marker actually is an image:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: feature.position,
            icon: 'youricon.png',
            map: map
          });
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/custom-markers