# How to personalize a Marker on Google Maps with CSS

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps

I have a google map on my html file and is working fine:)! Now I'm trying to personalize the Marker, I can change the img but I want also make it rounded with border-radius: 50%; and give it a border value too. Is that possible? right now I have the picture (squared) and I want to style it with css, is that even possible?

[image: example]

JAVASCRIPT

```
 function initMap() {
 // This is the minimum zoom level that we'll allow
 var minZoomLevel = 4;

 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapLayer'), {
 zoom: minZoomLevel,
 center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.50, -90.50),
 streetViewControl: false,
 mapTypeControl: false,
 scaleControl: false,
 gestureHandling: 'cooperative',
 scrollwheel: false,
 mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
 });

 // Bounds for world
 var strictBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
 new google.maps.LatLng(-54, -137.50),
 new google.maps.LatLng(81, 170.90));

 // Listen for the dragend event
 google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragend', function () {
 if (strictBounds.contains(map.getCenter())) return;

 // We're out of bounds - Move the map back within the bounds

 var c = map.getCenter(),
     x = c.lng(),
     y = c.lat(),
     maxX = strictBounds.getNorthEast().lng(),
     maxY = strictBounds.getNorthEast().lat(),
     minX = strictBounds.getSouthWest().lng(),
     minY = strictBounds.getSouthWest().lat();

 if (x < minX) x = minX;
 if (x > maxX) x = maxX;
 if (y < minY) y = minY;
 if (y > maxY) y = maxY;

 map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(y, x));
 });

 // Limit the zoom level
 google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function () {
 if (map.getZoom() < minZoomLevel) map.setZoom(minZoomLevel);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many possibilities to achieve that:

**Use RichMarker for Google Maps v3**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25048625/1087623

**Use CSS selector img src if you know the URL of the image to apply style**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25371006/1087623

**Add a class CSS to the marker Layer DIV then apply CSS style:**

http://bl.ocks.org/amenadiel/f4e5bd78b214ff081254

Comment: thanks @Taha Azzabi very useful! I've tried with RichMarker, modified the file directly on Jsfiddle, then when I used on my own file didn't work. I also implemented the RichMarker.js file and the other external link and nothing.

I like the 2nd one but, if I have several images? not sure why the Img has the link to the image repeated on the css? what If I want to create several markers? I should also repeat the css styles for all of them? (border-radius, border, shadow, etc)